# Tex стилистика CSS

Tags: css, latex, tex

Необходимо написать справку в формате `HTML`. Просят чтобы визуальная стилистика текста была похожа на `Tex`'овскую. Начиная от шрифта, заканчивая размером абзацев. Интересует готовый `css` sheet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[PubCSS](http://thomaspark.co/2015/01/pubcss-formatting-academic-publications-in-html-css/)** -  думаю это именно то что вам нужно

[ссылка на саму библиотеку](https://github.com/thomaspark/pubcss)